# WSO2 openID configuration

Tags: wso2, openid

I am trying to find out the WSO2 OpenID connect meta data URL.
Something similar to http://< URL >.well-known/openid-configuration.

Could someone tell me that ?

Answer (score 1):

Entity Server supports for the OpenId connect core specification which can be found from [here](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/asela/oauth/app/openid-connect/). If you like to try out the openid connect with Identity Server, you can find the sample from [here](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/asela/oauth/app/openid-connect/). You can even modify the source and rebuild the web application as you like.

You can check the following link for reference:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/OpenID+Connect+with+the+WSO2+Identity+Server+and+WSO2+OAuth2+Playground

http://xacmlinfo.org/2015/01/08/openid-connect-identity-server/

Comment: Do you have any samples using asp.net OWIN authentication with WSO2 identity server ?